# comparison of shell sorting and merge sorting

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

Comparing the running time of these two sorts, for some reason I get that they work in almost the same time, and on sorted arrays, shell sorting works 4 times faster. Although this can't be, because in the best case, shell sorting is performed in time n(log n)^2, while merge sorting is performed in nlogn time, which is faster than shell sorting. What could be the problem? I tried it on different PCs, but shell sorting is still faster.
UPD: For arrays filled randomly, it works as it should, but for already sorted ones, shell sorting works twice as fast.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DIFF 3276

double wtime(void);
void randArray(int* array, int size);
void shellSort(int a[], int size);
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r);

int main(void)
{
    FILE* file1;
    FILE* file2;
    int* array = NULL;

    unsigned seed = time(NULL);

    if (!(file1 = fopen("shell.txt", "w"))) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int step = DIFF; step <= 32760; step += DIFF) {
        srand(seed);
        array = (int*)malloc(step * sizeof(int));
        double start, end;

        randArray(array, step);

        start = wtime();
        shellSort(array, step);
        end = wtime();

        free(array);

        fprintf(file1, "%d\t%lf\n", step, end - start);
    }

    fclose(file1);

    if (!(file2 = fopen("merge.txt", "w"))) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int step = DIFF; step <= 32760; step += DIFF) {
        srand(seed);
        array = (int*)malloc(step * sizeof(int));
        double start, end;

        randArray(array, step);

        start = wtime();
        mergeSort(array, 0, step - 1);
        end = wtime();

        free(array);

        fprintf(file2, "%d\t%lf\n", step, end - start);
    }

    fclose(file2);
}

void randArray(int* array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
}

double wtime(void)
{
    struct timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    return (double)t.tv_sec + (double)t.tv_usec * 1E-6;
}

void shellSort(int a[], int size)
{
    int i, j;
    int s = size / 2;

    while (s > 0) {
        for (i = s; i < size; i++) {
            int temp = a[i];
            for (j = i - s; (j >= 0) && (a[j] > temp); j -= s)
                a[j + s] = a[j];
            a[j + s] = temp;
        }
        s /= 2;
    }
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;

    int L[n1], R[n2];

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;

        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: use the same numbers for both tests... `unsigned seed = time(NULL); srand(seed); /*shell*/ srand(seed); /*merge*/`

Comment: Maybe ... just maybe :-) ... maybe you're not measuring sorting speed.

Comment: I've done sorting for the same numbers, shell sorting works twice as fast :(

Comment: @pmg Try it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/F1GFLRZMm).

Comment: @Zakk If you try to compare an already sorted array, then shell sorting is much faster anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your shell sort works in-place and for a sorted array it never swaps a single element. So it only has the cost of the compares and the branch predictor will predict the compare perfectly every time.

Your merge sort on the other hand copies the data to temp arrays and back in every step. That's `2 * log(n)` copies of the whole array. The extra memory needed might also exceed the L1 cache of your CPU for the larger test runs making this magnitudes worse. You can cut that in half by alternating between 2 arrays, well almost `log(n) + 1` copies worst case. Branch prediction for the sorted case is perfect too, it's just the copies that cost you.

Comment: But all merge sorting even sorted array should be faster

Comment: It will be faster than merge sorting a random array. But it always copies while Shell Sort does not.